# How can I get getopts source?

Tags: bash, getopts

My embedded device uses busybox and it only has getopt. I wanted to port getopts to my embedded device and was looking for getopts source to do that. Where can I find getopts source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find it in bash source. You can download `bash` from [Here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/)

You will find `getopts.def` inside `builtins/` dir.
`mkbuiltins -D . getopts.def` will create getopts.c. 
You will have to do `configure` and `make` which will create `mkbuiltins` 
inside `builtins/` directory.

Comment: I am looking at bash source. But all it has it getopts.def